# Написать программу, которая получает число N из диапазона [1, 26] и Выводит большую букву N и маленькую букву n

Tags: c++, char, int

Нужно Написать программу, которая получает число N из диапазона [1, 26] и Выводит большую букву N и маленькую букву n . Не понимаю как решать задачу . Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Давайте вы не своими словами расскажете, а дадите точную формулировку задания.

Comment: И приведите свои попытки решения + дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу. Используйте кнопку править

Comment: Написать программу,которая при входе получает N число из диапазона [1, 26] и Выводит N n из латинского алфавита.

Comment: Задача должна быть решена с помощью Char . Это из темы ascii таблица и Char символы

Comment: Для решения этой задачи вам нужно знать, что коды латинских букв в ASCII расположены непрерывной последовательностью. Код 2-й буквы ("B"), на 1 больше чем код первой буквы ("A"). `char i = 'A'; i++; cout<<i;` выведет символ B

Comment: @ГерманБорисов *`char i = 'A'; i++; cout<<i;` выведет символ B* — необязательно

Comment: @dIm0n, в каком случае это будет не так?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов в любой реализации, где так не захотят. Стандарты C/C++ не дают гарантию на последовательно идущие коды букв

Comment: @dIm0n, у автора и у меня указано, что ASCII

Comment: @ГерманБорисов я выделил конкретную фразу с кодом, которая необязательно верна. Если бы вы сами написали, что этот код зависит от реализации, то я ничего бы не говорил

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю, что от вас хотят... Не этого ли?

```
int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    cout << char('A'+N-1) << "  " << char('a'+N-1) << endl;
}
```

(Кто соберется минусовать - без проблем, но это уже второй раз этот вопрос всплывает, проще ответить, чем закрывать :))